# How do I insert values from one table into another table?

Tags: select, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B. I am inserting a value from Table B to Table A. 
Table A has Column (Key,ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c,d,e,f). Table B has Column (Key,ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c,d,Group). Now I have statements like this,

```
Insert ##Table A
(Key,
ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c
)

Select
Key,
ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c)
From Table B where Key = "blah"
```

Now instead of selecting LOB from Table B, I want group column and those values to be inserted in the table A for column "LOB"

How do I do that?

Comment: sql server 2008 R2 thats what i m using

Comment: Could we get sample starting tables/data, and desired results?  This can help us see what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace LOB with Group in the SELECT

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Key, ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c ) 
SELECT Key, ID,Name,Group,a,b,c 
FROM Table B 
WHERE Key = "blah"
```

Comment: Ok so value from GROUP Column would be added in LOB column right? because After i m performing this operation I am using Table A to insert data into the another table.

Comment: That is correct yes, the two sets of columns will be matched up. ie; Key will be inserted with Key, ID with ID, Name with Name, LOB with Group, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Key,ID,Name,LOB,a,b,c) 
SELECT Key,ID,Name,[Group],a,b,c 
FROM TableB 
WHERE Key = "blah"
```

This should work assuming the data types for LOB and GROUP are the same.

Comment: @maina -- then that should work for you assuming you don't have table constraints on any of your fields etc.  Best of luck :)

Comment: Ok so value from GROUP Column would be added in LOB column right? because After i m performing this operation I am using Table A to insert data into the another table.Here in my case Table A is ##Tmp table.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Could not connect.");

if(!$db) 

    die("no db");

if(!mysql_select_db("database",$db))

    die("No database selected.");
$query="SELECT park_id,title FROM table1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$sql= "INSERT into table2 (type,id,title) VALUES ('value','$rows[park_id]','$rows[title]')";
mysql_query($sql);
}





?>
```